# apache-camel file2 antInclude ignore-case

Tags: file, include, apache-camel, ignore-case

I need to poll a directory and narrow the files with a case insentive expression.

With version 2.10 camel adds support for antInclude which is what I look into, unfortunately antInclude is case sensitive, so are other filtering expressions. Implementing GenericFileFilter is not an option, since the filtering patterns are not known at compile time as I read them from database at runtime and I have multiple file rules each with a different pattern.

I programmatically create several routes in a loop, where each file route has a different case insensitive filtering pattern. I would appreciate if camel file component supports case insensitive expressions, or is there any other way without creating myself a new file component in camel?

```
public class MyRouter extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    Vector<FileTransferEntity> list = TransferDAO.getTransferList();
    for(FileTransferEntity t : list) {
        fromF("ftp://ftpuser@ftpserver/some-directory?antInclude=%s", t.getFileMask()).
        toF("mock:result");//depending on t, action will change.
    }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you report this as an improvement to the Camel @user mailing list, or as a JIRA ticket in the Camel JIRA tracker. I am sure it would be possible to have antInclude be case insensitive.

Comment: thx, added https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-4963

Answer (score 0):

should be able to use a custom filter instead...see [camel-file2](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) for information or see this example...

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/file/FileConsumerFileFilterTest.java

Comment: thx boday, but I can not use custom filter since I read filters from database there is no way to correlate the filters with the routes.